# Can I use a 900W UPS with 1100W system if I need to cover blips only?

Tags: power-supply, ups

I may get unstable voltage or lose power for less than 2 seconds in winter season. I have a system that **consumes** 1000-1100W. Is it enough to get a 900W UPS for that purpose? I don't care if system will shutdown abruptly, but don't want to fry it in case of a bad thunderstorm :)

Would 900W UPS be able to a) stabilize voltage and b) withstand 1-2 sec outage?

If at least (a) is true it could work for me.

I'd like to avoid investing into 1100+W UPS as both price and size of the unit aren't very convenient :)

**update**
According to manufacturer spec, it should work:
Protection Overload: The UPS automatically shuts down if overload exceeds 110% nominal at 60 sec and 130% at 3 second.

The question is, this overload alarm will work in LINE mode or in BACKUP only. It's not clear from the docs.

Comment: why not just get a 1100W UPS?

Comment: If a system draws 1100 Watts and you lose power, a UPS supplying 900 watts will not be enough to sustain the system, so something will be turned off.  If this is a monitor then it will be turned off, if it’s a GPU, then the system will crash obviously.  Neither A or B is true.

Comment: Keltari, obviously, after 900W the price explodes

Comment: Ramhound, system crash is fine. As long as components aren't damaged.

Comment: Are you sure your system actually consumes 1000-1100W? How did you determine this?

Comment: @stim, the UPS wouldn't buy you anything over having nothing at all (except maybe built in surge protection, which isn't the issue you're interested in).  The UPS wattage rating is the limit at which the internal breaker disables it.  So if the load is over 900W, the UPS won't provide any benefit.

Comment: @fixer1234 Specifically the UPD wouldn’t sustain the system if the voltage draw exceeds its capacity just like what happens in CA when people turn their AC on during the summer

Comment: How do you know your system draws 1000W+? That is really, really unlikely.

Comment: 4 x 1080ti cards.

Comment: @stim That would do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in connecting a system that really draw 1,100 W or so to a 900W UPS. Best case, the 900W UPS will still be able to stabilize the voltage a little if it's a UPS that has that capability and it will also help protect against surges and spikes. The worst case scenario is that the UPS constantly alarms due to overload, pops its fuse, or fails to do anything at all.

A UPS is just the wrong tool for the job. A 1200W voltage stabilizer will be cheaper, smaller, and better at that job, and it wouldn't be constantly overloaded.

Low-end 900W AVR UPS: $160
Mid-range 1200W line conditioner: $110

If you want to protect against power dropouts of a second or more, you need an appropriately-sized UPS. A power conditioner won't do that.

Comment: I haven't measured, but 4 x 1080Ti cards should draw around 1kW at peak.

Comment: @stim That's what I would do. I think it makes sense to spend reasonable amounts on good power protection.